# TypeScript type for return of Reselect Redux function?

Tags: typescript, reselect

Is it possible to define the return type of the `createSelector` function in Redux's Reselect?

I couldn't figure this out from the official docs: https://github.com/reduxjs/reselect#q-are-there-typescript-typings

This cheatsheet also doesn't seem to provide this:
https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide#selectors-with-reselect

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

import { TodosState } from './reducer';

export const getTodos = (state: TodosState) => state.todos;

export const getTodosFilter = (state: TodosState) => state.todosFilter;

export const getFilteredTodos = createSelector(getTodos, getTodosFilter, (todos, todosFilter) => {
  switch (todosFilter) {
    case 'completed':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed);
    case 'active':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed);

    default:
      return todos;
  }
});
```

If I know that the return from `getFilteredTodos` is something like this:

```
type Return = {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
}[]
```

Then can I define this?

Comment: As I am aware you need to define only the last function return if it is wrongly infered. So it should be just `(todos, todosFilter): {
  text: string;
  completed: boolean;
}[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the return like so:

```
export const getFilteredTodos = createSelector(getTodos, getTodosFilter, (todos, todosFilter) : { text: string; completed: boolean; }[] => {
  switch (todosFilter) {
    case 'completed':
      return todos.filter(t => t.completed);
    case 'active':
      return todos.filter(t => !t.completed);

    default:
      return todos;
  }
});
```